# Javascript + ReactJS: Why doesn't regex .match() not return consistently?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I have the following multi-line string displayed using `<pre>` like the following where each line is represented using new line:

```
SchoolDistrictCode:291238-9
location_version:3.4
build:e9kem
```

And I would like to parse `build:e9kem` out, and every time the content of the multi-line will vary. But it will have `build:` in every one.

I attempted it with:

```
const regexp = /^build:(.*)$/m;

//stringPar would vary every time
const stringPar = `SchoolDistrictCode:291238-9
location_version:3.4
build:e9kem`;
```

Attempt to display it like so:

```
{stringPar.match(regexp)[1])};
```

It parses correctly, but for certain multi-line string, it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` when I try to display the string such as `stringPar.match(regexp)[1]`, but it console logs the string properly when console logged like console.log(stringPar.match(regexp)[1]).

What could possibly be the issue?

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept answer

**EDIT (In ReactJS)**

It's basically a component that's being rendered over and over, with the props being passed into it.

```
export default class tableRow extends Component {
     ...

     render() {
          console.log(this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)[1]);

          return (
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   {/*Even tried {this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)[1]==null? " ": this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)} but still getting the same error*/}
                   <button>{this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)[1]}</button>
                 <td>
               <tr>
          )
     }
}
```

Comment: *"for certain multi-line string"*: please give a concrete example. Your problem could also be linked with asynchronous code. Could you please provide a code snippet that has the `console.log` that fails in the same code block, and that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @trincot Please take a look at the Edit

Comment: If the error you get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` then it means that the return of `this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)` is returning null, not the value in the array, hence why the check you tried may not have worked. It looks like the regex is failing sometimes.

Comment: @jonowzz but I attempted `{/*Even tried {this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)[1]==null? " ": this.props.stringPar.match(regexp)} but still getting the same error*/}` but when I do `console.log(stringPar.match(regexp)[1])` it works though.

Comment: There is no concrete example of failure in your question. Please provide a snippet that we can use to *reproduce* the problem. Possibly in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

> What could possibly be the issue?

The regex is not matching in all cases probably because:

> every time the content of the multi-line will vary

Do something like this so you can see what the string looks like when it doesn't match:

```
export default class tableRow extends Component {
     ...

     render() {
          // ensure we actually have a string to run match on so don't get an error
          const matchStr = this.props.stringPar || ''; 
          const m = matchStr.match(regexp); // run match
          const matchFound = m && m.length > 0; // boolean, was match found
          const build = matchFound ? m[1] : 'build fallback'; // regex match or fallback if no match was found

          if (!matchFound) {
            console.log("Could not find 'build:' in:", matchStr, matchStr.length === 0 ? 'BLANK!' : 'NOT BLANK');               
          }

          return (
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   <button>{build}</button>
                 <td>
               <tr>
          )
     }
}
```

and adjust your regex accordingly.

Comment: Appreciate the response but for some components the same error will stop the program at `this.props.stringPar.match(regexp);`.  What kind of check should I do there?

Comment: @JoKo Sounds like sometimes the prop isn't set. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @JoKo Not sure I follow. Is it sometimes `build` and sometimes `dailyBuild`?

Comment: sorry meant `build`! Actually got it to work! But do you mind commenting briefly on what each line is intended to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JoKo. Sure, updated. Let me know if anything isn't clear.